# How can I get a value of an item that the user chose from preferences?

Tags: android

I wanna make a simple android app with a Checkbox preference which when the user checks, it prompts the user to confirm when they try to close the app... If they don't check it the app closes immediately without any alertDialog! Please...I just need a simple snippet.

Comment: What do you mean by "preference" exactly?  Are you talking about Android's preferences facility, or are you just looking to get a checkbox on the screen that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't do the research for you on Preference input handle and saving data. Yet, I can give you an idea. Create a boolean flag in your preference activity, check if checkbox is checked by isChecked(), and manage the boolean flag accordingly. Then when you are done, put this boolean flag into SharedPreference, and get that SharedPreference from whereever you want. This is a basic thing, so I'm pretty sure you can find more by little research.